# Click div with same id

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to click on a div but the div in question shares the same ID as another div. I have tested several solutions, especially with xpath, but nothing works.

Is there any other solution to click without selector and xpath ?

html

```
<div class="modal-button" id="button-grey"> Cancel </div>

<div class="modal-button create-modal-button modal-blue-button" id="button-grey"> Accept </div>
```

My code :

```
await page.click('#button-grey')
```

With this code, It clicks cancel when I'd like it to click accept.

Thank advance for your help

Comment: use onClick event on the elements.

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be *unique*, precisely because you use them to select specific elements. If you cannot change the HTML, use a selector like `.modal-button:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Why is it so that you want to give same id to both div ? 
Try giving different ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possibly clicking cancel because the first div it encounters with the id button-grey is your div that says cancel.

Ids are supposed to be unique. Instead try making button-grey a class and add it as an additional class to both divs. Then give the div that says accept a unique id. Use this unique id within await page.click(yourUniqueID).

Answer (score 1):

As Chris G has mentioned, `id` attributes are meant to be unique to that specific element.

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) describes an `id` attribute as the following:

> The `id` global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

Don't use `onClick()`, but simply change the ids to something more descriptive that are **unique**. It also makes finding specific elements in your code much easier.

If you cannot change the code, for example if you are web scraping and need them elements, you can use `.modal-button:nth-child()` to find whatever button you need.

Answer (score 1):

your html is not valid, you can't set serval html tag with the same id.

check your html in [W3C validator]: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Transform your "button-grey" id to class

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, id's must be unique.

> With this code, It clicks cancel when I'd like it to click accept?

This happens because the browser will use the first element it finds with that `id` because it only ever expects to find one. In your case, the first one found is for `cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a faulty HTML code that has multiple items with the same id (which is supposed to be unique). As your question is:

> Is there any other solution to click without selector and xpath?

here is a solution with [`elementHandle.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions) on the 2nd element `[1]` with the same id:

```js
const elementHandles = await page.$$('#button-grey')
await elementHandles[1].click() // click 2nd element [1] with the same id
```

---

Anyway, XPaths can be useful sometimes if you have to click something based on its text content:

```js
const acceptHandle = await page.$x("//div[@id='button-grey' and contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
await acceptHandle[0].click() // XPath returns an array, the first item [0] is the matching element
```